# How to use targets to launch multiple apps using the same code base?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an iOS project and I want to have several apps in the store with the same code base, but slight changes in assets and some features enabled in an app and other features in another.

I read in some blogs I can do it using some deferent targets...

How Can I Do It?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use targets to set user defined properties, set different assets to each target and enable features in a target and disable them on another. I created a blog here with the details of this process. [how to use targets to launch multiple](http://khaledannajar.blogspot.com.eg/2017/02/how-to-use-targets-to-launch-multiple.html)